# Shell script best way to remove files not in a pair

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I have a set of files that come in pairs:

```
/var/log/messages-20111001
/var/log/messages-20111001.hash
```

I've had several of these rotate away and now I'm left with a ton of `/var/log/messages-201110xx.hash` files with no associated log.  I'd like to clean up the mess, but I'm uncertain how to remove a file that isn't part of a "pair".  I can use bash or zsh (or any LSB tool, really).  I need to remove all the .hash files that don't have an associated log.

Example

```
/var/log/messages-20111001.hash
/var/log/messages-20111002.hash
/var/log/messages-20111003.hash
/var/log/messages-20111004.hash
/var/log/messages-20111005
/var/log/messages-20111005.hash
/var/log/messages-20111006
/var/log/messages-20111006.hash
```

Should be reduced to:

```
/var/log/messages-20111005
/var/log/messages-20111005.hash
/var/log/messages-20111006
/var/log/messages-20111006.hash
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for file in *.hash; do test -f "${file%.hash}" || rm -- "$file"; done
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I wasn't aware of the ${file%.hash} usage.  Thanks.

Comment: My files don't have spaces, but if they did, I think `for file in *.hash; do test -f "${file%.hash}" || rm "$file"; done` would work

Comment: For the feint of heart, try `mkdir -p /tmp/to_be_discarded; for file in *.hash; do test -f "${file%.hash}" || mv -- "$file" /tmp/to_be_discarded; done` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
for f in /var/log/messages-????????.hash ; do
    [[ -e "${f%.hash}" ]] || rm "$f"
done
```